# How to fix ' The call "preventDefault ()" on a "touchmove" event from a listener registered as "passive" was ignored. '

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-browser

I'm developping a web application. But in smartphone, i got some problems that I don't know where it comes from.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_suggested', function(e){
        var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
        var receiver_id = $(this).attr('data-receiver_id');
        $.ajax({
            url:"./includes/ajax/add_suggested.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                action: action,
                receiver_id: receiver_id
            },
            success: function(){
                if(action == 'add-link'){
                    $('#suggested_btn1-' + receiver_id).html('<a class="btn add_suggested col white indigo-text text-darken-2" data-action="cancel-link" data-receiver_id="'+ receiver_id +'">Annuler</a>');

                } else if(action == 'cancel-link'){
                    $('#suggested_btn1-' + receiver_id).html('<a style="display:flex; align-items: center;" class="btn add_suggested col indigo darken-2" data-action="add-link" data-receiver_id="'+ receiver_id +'"><i class="material-icons">person_add</i> Linker</a>');

                }
            }
        })
    })
```

It works on pc but if I use mobile devices it stop working.

the error displayed in the console:
[image: the error displayed in the console]

> The call "preventDefault ()" on a "touchmove" event from a listener registered as "passive" was ignored.

Comment: Are you actually certain this comes from jQuery, and this snippet particularly? Passive event listeners are scheduled for 4.x, and I don't actually see a `click` -> `touchmove` conversion in the jQuery source code itself.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I don't know really. But it's the message that displayed in the console?  have you an idea about this?

Comment: Are you using `jquery-mobile`?

Comment: That's not an error, it's just a warning, and doesn't prevent the code from working.

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with `touchmove`, and doesn't call `preventDefault()`. The warning must be coming from somewhere else.